# Android: downloading large zipped file

Tags: java, android, file, zip, download

I've got problem in downloading large zipped file in Android. When I'm downloading small file (i.e. 20 mb) everything is ok, but when I am trying to download large file (i.e 100 mb) I cannot unzip it after downloading because it is corrupt.
Here is my code:

```
        final URL url = new URL(URL));
        final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), params[0]);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream fos;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        InputStream input = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = bis.read(buffer);

        while(read != -1){
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            read = bis.read(buffer);
        }

        fos.close();
        bis.close();
```